# Show users quotas in Azure since they don't know how to use portal.azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My App Service in Azure is free. In `portal.azure` I can watch `Quotas` and monitor if I'm closing to the limits. Is there a way to show these `Qoatas` to users without the access to the `portal.azure`? Those users are in the same `Active Directory` where the app rests but they have no knowledge on how to use `portal.azure`.

Edit: I've added the screenshot asked by @Jay

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let them use the REST API - [App Service Plans - List Usages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/listusages#code-try-0), click the `Try it` button to login, specify the parameters then run.

[image]

This part in the response like below is that you can see in the portal.

```
  {
      "unit": "Bytes",
      "nextResetTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
      "currentValue": 20480,
      "limit": 53687091200,
      "name": {
        "value": "FileSystemStorage",
        "localizedValue": "File System Storage"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What  do you mean by `Try` button?

Comment: @Pomme I mean the green `Try it` button, the link I provide is after clicking the button.

Comment: In the navigation bar I have `Free account >` in green. There is not `Try it`. Which is weird since I have portal.azure account and I'm logged in while viewing this page...

Comment: @Pomme Could you try [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/listusages) again in an incognito window, because the `Try it` button is always there, not related to the account type. If you still have the issue, please update the screenshot in your question.

Comment: I've provided the screenshot in incognito mode

Comment: @Pomme The screenshot is that you request `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/listusages` without any other operation? If so, I think it may be related to your browser, the `Try it` should always be there like https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVO3a.png You could change a browser to have a try.